# Excel - Transform / Extract data from a single column/cell to multiple columns cells

Tags: excel, transform, extract

Can someone show how I would format/transform a ton of these types of data...

(single cell, one column)

| 040/2.5OZ |

| 001/20#   |

| 012/2.8#  |

To this

(three cells, three columns)

| 40 | 2.5 | OZ |

| 01 | 20  |  # |

| 12 | 2.8 |  # |

Thanks!

Comment: Filterxml would be best fit but problem is last character. How many variant to last character like #, OZ? Only these two always.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula-

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>"),"#","</s><s>#"),"OZ","</s><s>OZ")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

Comment: This works very well, i have to add a SUBSTITUTE and Corresponding text identifier which made it a bit long but works! Is it possible to add a cell between the first and second? In example | 40 | empty cell  | 2.5  | OZ | ?